# Vuetify theme is being ignored

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have created a file in my plugins directory which looks like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib/framework";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: "#081d4d", // $blue
        secondary: "#00c8b7", // $jade
        //anchor: "#081d4d", // $blue (by default vuetify styles anchors with the same colour of primary)

        accent: "#82B1FF", // $blue
        error: "#ff4438", // $warm-red
        info: "#835dd0", // $violet
        success: "#4CAF50", // none
        warning: "#ff8204", // $orange
      },
    },
  },
});
```

And then I use it in my **main.ts** like this:

```
import "./registerServiceWorker";

import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

import { provide } from "@vue/composition-api";
import { DefaultApolloClient } from "@vue/apollo-composable";

import "./plugins/axios";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import apolloClient from "./plugins/vue-apollo";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  setup() {
    provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient);
  },
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

When I use a button or alert and set their colours, it's not using my theme.
Also, even if I try to change to the dark theme, nothing happens.
This is the template:

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="section section-white">
          <h1>This is a test</h1>
          <p>With some tests content</p>

          <v-btn color="primary">Test</v-btn>
          <v-alert type="info"></v-alert>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is what my UI looks like:

[image]

As far as I can tell, I have followed the directions correctly, so I have no idea why this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this from

```
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib/framework";
```

to

```
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib";
```

Moreover, if you are not able to use `theme` attributes directly use it like this.

```
<v-btn :color="$vuetify.theme.themes["light"].primary">Test</v-btn>
```

or you can also use `computed` property for that

```
computedPrimaryColor(){
 return this.$vuetify.theme.themes["light"].primary;
}
```

and use it like

```
<v-btn color="computedPrimaryColor">Test</v-btn>
```

Comment: why does that work? and can't I get it to just use primary instead of the `:color="$vuetify.theme.themes['light'].primary"` ?